# Change background image with the slider image simultaneously - jquery/css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the background image when slider will rotate with one image to another image simultaneously. For this example, I added a bootstrap carousel slider with a background image. I want when the slider image will slide, then the background image will also change/slide at the same time. I have used two bootstrap carousel slider before, one was main slider and the other was background slider. But I need to add only a main carousel slider and background image which also change with the main slider image. Here is my example url link (http://ronysatiar.com/demoo/index.html) where I want to use this type of functionality. Any idea, guys!

Comment: When you say "slider", do you mean the three center circle icons? It's not exactly clear what you mean.

Comment: Not actually the center circle. When the slider image will slide the background image(bellow the slider image) should change simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background image with JQuery just like any other CSS property:

```
$("header").css('background', 'url(path to my image)');
```

If you want the change to be triggered by the slide event, follow this example from the bootstrap docs:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  $("header").css('background', 'url(path to my image)');
});
```

Hope that helps,
db

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have read the docs. But I could not understand how to use the event due to lack of jquery knowledge. I think your help will find me a solution.